# JDBC connection to the microsoft sql

Tags: java

```
The TCP/IP connection to the host <Instance name>, port 1433 has failed. Error: "<intance name. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:231)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.convertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:282)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2578)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:719)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3523)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:3172)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:3014)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1836)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1246)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:252)
    at JDBC.main(JDBC.java:9)
```

code:-

```
import java.sql.*;

import java.*;

class JDBC {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String con = "jdbc:sqlserver://<instancename>;instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=DB;integratedSecurity=true";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(con);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT *FROM STUDENT";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("done");
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

I tried many solution but it's not working,
and confusion about which jar file I should add in my project>libray>module.

```
mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre8.jar
mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre8-javadoc.jar
mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre8-sources.jar
mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre11.jar
mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre11-javadoc.jar
mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre11-sources.jar
```

Comment: Have you checked: *Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.*

Comment: https://help.dugeo.com/m/Insight/l/438913-troubleshooting-enabling-tcp-ip-in-the-sql-server Might Help

Answer (score 0):

CAN YOU try this instead

Replace  with the actual hostname or IP address of your SQL Server.

Comment: still it's not working